# NodeJS/Socket.io How to use multiple ports (listeners)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

i want to run more ports for my NodeJS.
Everytime when more users joining my site and send emits, it gets more laggy.
I want to prevent from this. But how?

I think a good way is to upstream some nodes with nginx

```
upstream nodes {
    ip_hash;

    server localhost:2055;
    server localhost:2056;
    server localhost:2057;
}
```

Than i want to start new listeners

```
server.listen(2055, function(){
     console.log('Express listening on port', this.address().port);
});
server.listen(2056, function(){
     console.log('Express listening on port', this.address().port);
});
server.listen(2057, function(){
    console.log('Express listening on port', this.address().port);
});
```

But for any reason only 2055 is starting and logging in console :/

Any Ideas?

Comment: You can't have the SAME server object listen on three different ports.  You can to create a separate server object for each port you want to listen on.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a different server object for each port like this because each server object can only listen in one port.

```
ports = [2055,2056,2057];
    ports.forEach(function(port) {
    s = http.createServer(reqHandler);
    s.listen(port);
    servers.push(s);
});
```

Comment: I tried with that:
`ports = [2055,2056,2057];
ports.forEach(function(port) {
    server.listen(port, function(){
   console.log('Express listening on port', this.address().port);
 });
    servers.push(server);
});`

But not working. Only 2055 will start with it...

Comment: What is your configuration ? In my mac it starts in all 3 ports. You should write a request handler to check it out and be sure that it responds in all 3 ports.

Comment: What i read is, that http can only run one port at same time... i dont know why you can run 3 than... thats my header `const http = require('http'); const app = express(); const server = http.Server(app);` http.Server is same to createServer